# Properties preserved in addition of ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, ideals, prime-ideals, complete-intersection

If I and J are prime (radical) ideals then what are the conditions under which we can define a prime (radical) ideal from I+J?

Comment: You mean when is $I+J$ still radical? Cause otherwise take $\sqrt{I+J}$...

Comment: Yes when I+J is still radical.